# Azure Functions: There was an error performing a read operation on the Blob Storage Secret Repository

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

In testing Azure Functions locally, I am receiving this error:

> "There was an error performing a read operation on the Blob Storage
> Secret Repository. Please ensure the 'AzureWebJobsStorage' connection
> string is valid."

I have Azure Blob Storage setup, including Storage Emulator and Storage Explorer. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

I had this issue with Azure Durable Functions, I found the way to resolve it here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3795#issuecomment-430337085

In `local.settings.json`, add a new setting called `AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType` and set it to "files".

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files"
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Maybe the push to replace Azure Storage Emulator on Windows has been a little hasty

Comment: After ~2+ years this just bit me.  `"AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files"` appears to have automagically been required.

Comment: As per Aaron Hudson, adding "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files" fixed my previously working local store debug setup. I had just introduced a timer trigger function, so maybe that changed runtime behaviour. Be careful about copying the "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" setting above if targeting isolated functions.

Answer (score 23):

My Two cents.

I am trying to run a durable function on my local computer.

I was getting this error.

> There was an error performing a read operation on the Blob Storage Secret Repository. Please ensure the 'AzureWebJobsStorage' connection string is valid

I looked at [this answer from the github issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite/issues/1179#issuecomment-974323449).

I completely deleted my folder the path for which is as follows

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\Azurite
```

Now things are running fine again.

The folder looks like this.

[image: Azurite folder on Windows]

Note: User noted it worked but had to delete my entire Temp folder - deleting the Azurite folder was not enough to resolve the issue

Comment: This worked for me but I had to delete my entire Temp folder - deleting the Azurite folder was not enough to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 12):

Please do not change the "AzureWebJobsStorage" parameter to your live storage account, as additional costs can occur and you maybe have unforeseen side effects or impact on you online environment.
The storage emulator is long deprecated, you should use azurite to emulate storage locally. You can download azurite for example with npm (`npm install -g azurite`) or in many other [ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio).

"UseDevelopmentStorage=true" is exactly the correct setting to use in a local environment, especially when you are going to use durable functions or other compute or I/O heavy tasks.
Regarding you problem, azurite creates multiple json files in the folder where you execute it for its virtual storage backend. If you run azurite without any parameters, the following files should be existent:

- __azurite_db_blob_extent__.json
- __azurite_db_queue__.json
- __azurite_db_queue_extent__.json
- __azurite_db_table__.json

In addition there are normally two or more folders called similar to this:

- __blobstorage__
- __queuestorage__

To force the azure-functions-core-tools runtime to reset storage claims and handles, first stop azurite and all `func` instances, delete the above files and folders and start it again (azurite first).

All the content will of course be gone, but local development storage should never be used for persistent data.

Comment: If Azurite was auto-started by Visual Studio, you can find the file location by going to the Output window, selecting "Service Dependencies", and finding the line near the top of scrollback where it starts Azurite. The location of the above files is passed as --location.

Answer (score 6):

None of the other answers worked for me so I'll share my solution here. I tried:

- Changing `AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType`
- Killing the azurite process and restarting it
- Removing all the files from AppData

None of that worked. The fix for me was to install azurite using `npm install -g azurite` and then run it with `azurite`. After that my old project started working again.

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me -

Run cmd as admin.

run command
`netstat -ano | findstr :10000`
and coppy the PID of first IP address. In my case it was `18220`.

Then run `taskkill /PID 18220 /F`

After that run `"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" init` to re initilize the Azure Storage Emulator.

And finally run `"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" start` to start the Azure Storage Emulator.

Comment: Out of all the solutions, this worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio 2019 or later, you need to be sure "Azurite" services running.

How to be sure? -restart the VS and check output window
[image: VS Output window]

If you are using VS Code or Rider you should run Azurite manually.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution:

The error you're encountering typically happens when Azurite isn't installed or running on your machine. Azurite is the local emulator for Azure Storage services (Blob, Queue, and Table) that emulates the corresponding azure cloud services in your computer. Your Durable Function attempts to connect to the emulated Blob Storage, which is unavailable, hence the error. Here's how to resolve this:

1. Open your terminal/command prompt and install azurite if not installed

> ```
> npm install -g azurite
> ```

2. run azurite

> ```
> azurite -s -l
> ```

3. in your project, open local.settings.json and add "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files" as follows:

> ```
> {
>   "IsEncrypted": false,
>   "Values": {
>     "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
>     "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
>     "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files"
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else who continues to get blob read errors after setting `"AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "Files"`, downgrading the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage` package from v5 to v4 can fix it. (I used `v4.0.5`).

This may be specific to .NET projects. If you are new to modifying c# dependencies, in your `.csproj` file find the PackageReference object and change the version. You can then run `dotnet restore` to update/refresh.

For those that don't like reading text:

`project-name.csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
      ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    ...
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.5"/>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

For the sake of SEO, this was my error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Secret initialization from Blob storage failed due to missing both an Azure Storage connection string and a SAS connection uri. For Blob Storage, please provide at least one of these. If you intend to use files for secrets, add an App Setting key 'AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType' with value 'Files'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this for a day or so, turns out I just needed to install a NuGet package

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage